# When using getFilter in ListView the SharedPreference gets the wrong index

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView which uses ArrayAdapter and I also implemented the `getFilter` function to search within the `ListView`. I am using `SharedPreference` to get the index of the `ListView` to display some information on the next Activity. When searching, if the index is different it causes my app to show wrong information.

```
case 0:
                    tvT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                    strT = tvT.getText().toString();
                    inPos = strT.indexOf(".");
                    strT = strT.substring(0, inPos);
                    inPos = Integer.valueOf(strT);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(inPos), 2000).show();
                    //moveToActivity(String.valueOf(inPos-1)); //0
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tvT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                    strT = tvT.getText().toString();
                    inPos = strT.indexOf(".");
                    strT = strT.substring(0, inPos);
                    inPos = Integer.valueOf(strT);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(inPos), 2000).show();
                    //moveToActivity("1"); //1
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tvT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                    strT = tvT.getText().toString();
                    inPos = strT.indexOf(".");
                    strT = strT.substring(0, inPos);
                    inPos = Integer.valueOf(strT);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(inPos), 2000).show();
                    //moveToActivity("2"); //2
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tvT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                    strT = tvT.getText().toString();
                    inPos = strT.indexOf(".");
                    strT2 = strT.substring(0, inPos);
                    inPos = Integer.valueOf(strT2);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strT, 2000).show();
                    //moveToActivity("3"); //3
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tvT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                    strT = tvT.getText().toString();
                    inPos = strT.indexOf(".");
                    strT2 = strT.substring(0, inPos);
                    inPos = Integer.valueOf(strT2);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(inPos), 2000).show();
                    //moveToActivity("4"); //4
                    break;


public void moveToActivity(String strWhich) {
        editor.putString("NamePosition", strWhich);
        editor.commit();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NameDisplay.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
    }
```

Sample of my Activity:

[image]

The `case 0` code works except for `case 1` `case 2` and so forth up to `case 99` it's the same inPos which is 1. How do I make it so that no matter what the position is the number for the index always stays the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with the following:

```
String check = String.valueOf(dataList.getItemAtPosition(position));
int pos = check.indexOf(".");
int pos2 = check.indexOf(" ");
String strP = check.substring(pos2+1, pos);
int pos3 = Integer.valueOf(strP) - 1;

switch(position) {
    case 0:
    Log.i("pos", String.valueOf(pos));
    Log.i("pos2", String.valueOf(pos2));
    Log.i("strP", strP);
    Log.i("check", check);
    moveToActivity(String.valueOf(pos3)); //0
    break;
    case 1:
        moveToActivity(String.valueOf(pos3)); //1
        break;
    case 2:
        moveToActivity(String.valueOf(pos3)); //2
        break;
    case 3:
        moveToActivity(String.valueOf(pos3)); //3
        break;
}
```

Comment: I actually got rid of the entire `Switch` case and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assuming which position each element will have, you have two alternatives:

1. use `adapter.getItem(position)` and work from there.
2. implement `adapter.getItemId(position)` and switch the id of the item, instead of the position (your adapter will have to implement `getItemId(int position)`

Comment: I was trying to extract the `title` but it always returns the first one no matter which one is selected
How would the `getItem(position)` work if while searching it changes the position? It seems ONLY the hardcoded number works but then it looses the value once the search causes the index to change :/

Comment: getItem(position) (even if the reported position is 1) doesn't give you the right item? Then your code must be modifying `position`